# How can I obtain a rectangle with camshift algorithm?

Tags: c++, opencv

With the function

```
 cvMeanShift(&backproj, trackWindow,cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 15, 1 ),&track_comp);
```

I can obtain a rectangle, `aux=track_comp.rect;`

But with this

```
RotatedRect trackBox = CamShift(backproj, trackWindow,TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1 ));
```

How can I obtain a rectangle? not a rotated rectangle.

Comment: with `Rect cv::RotatedRect::boundingRect()`

Comment: ok, i´ll try with this

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is unclear, but the `CamShift` function modifies `trackWindow` to the latest position of the object. (`trackWindow` is passed by reference). You should use the same `trackWindow`variable for initialization of tracking for the next frame.

`trackbox.boundingRect()` turns out to not give the same `Rect` as the one written to `trackWindow`. `trackbox.boundingRect()` is bigger than the `Rect` written to `trackWindow`.

This answer is for opencv 2.4.5.0 and above. It probably holds for all opencv 2.0 and above though, but I have not verified this.